# PHP: extract($_POST) then get_defined_vars() returns nothing.... why?

Tags: php, post, extract

I have the following PHP script:

```
<?php 
  function dump_extracted_post() {
    extract($_POST);
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
  }
  dump_extracted_post();
?>
```

To this script, I post a form containing some data, and it produces the following (unexpected) result:

```
Array(0) {
}
```

**Why do I not see the the posted data?**

Is there something I've missed in my understanding of extract() or get_defined_vars()?  Is there some sort of security setting that might be interfering with extracting from $_POST ?

I am aware of the frowned upon nature of extract, so perhaps it's a security issue, but scanning the php docs doesn't seem to mention any such issue.  I want to use this to do some simple templating.

If I change the script to:

```
<?php 
  function dump_extracted_post() {
    var_dump($_POST);
  }
  dump_extracted_post();
?>
```

I see the posted data as expected (so yes, I am definately posting data).

Likewise, if I change the script to:

```
<?php 
  function dump_extracted_post() {
    $a = 'moocows';
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
  }
  dump_extracted_post();
?>
```

I see the expected output:

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(7) "moocows"
}
```

Comment: Your function works fine on my localhost. Have you checked to see if `extract()` is disabled on your server?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled and working: `extract(array('a'=>'b')); var_dump(get_defined_vars());` works as I expect... (just not when I replace the array with $_POST).  Running PHP 5.3.2.

Comment: Your original function works fine for me too.  Could you please show your HTML form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original function works fine for me.  I used the following script (named `extract.php`) for testing:

```
<form method="post" aciton="extract.php">
  <input type="text" name="foo" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<pre>
<?php
  function dump_extracted_post() {
    extract($_POST);
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
  }
  dump_extracted_post();
?>
</pre>
```

Function `extract` extracts only those `key=>value` pairs where key is valid identifier not conflicting with existing variables.  So probably keys in your `$_POST` are either not a valid identifiers or are conficting with existing variables.

Comment: One good thing to use with extract() is the EXTR_SKIP, like this extract($_POST,EXTR_SKIP); - it will avoid the user to change variables like _SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT] through url

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate the problem (it worked normally on my machine), so MAYBE it may be a problem with the keys/values you are inserting.
It may be tedious, but you should test each of your POST parameters. This is my suggestion:

(1) Try with a test array (This should work, as you stated)

```
function dump_extracted_post() {
    $postParams = array('testkey' => 'testval');

    extract($postParams);
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
}
dump_extracted_post();
```

(2) Put all your POST key/values in that array and try again

```
function dump_extracted_post() {
    $postParams = array('testkey' => 'testval');
    foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
        $postParams[$k] = $v;
    }

    extract($postParams);
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
}
dump_extracted_post();
```

If (2) fails, it means that something in your $_POST is causing a problem.

Test your results by inserting the POST parameters one-by-one,
and you should run into a point where it fails.

```
function dump_extracted_post() {
    $postParams = array('testkey' => 'testval');
    $i=1;
    foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
        if ($i > 1) break;  // increment this value each time, and see where the extract fails
        $postParams[$k] = $v;
        $i++;
    }

    extract($postParams);
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
}
dump_extracted_post();
```

If you successfully encounter a POST parameter which causes the extract to fail,
you can solve it (or comeback to stackoverflow with a new question).

Comment: Thanks, yes, the fields contained hyphens.